# Usage Too, As well and Also in negative sentences

Tags: adverbs

> I **also/too** don't understand why they're here

Is this sentence correct? My grammar book is saying that this sentence is wrong and we should use **either** in negative sentences. For example above sentence should be “I don’t understand why they are here either”.

But I feel like using too/also/as well is still fine in negative sentences.Are they wrong? How does the meaning of a sentence differ if we use them instead of “either”?

Answer (score 2):

"Also" can work perfectly well, but with a different meaning: you have previously stated an object clause and are adding another object clause to the action of the subject and verb:

> - (You) I don't know who they are.
> - (You) I also don't understand why they're here.

In contrast, "either" can apply a previously-stated action to   a new subject:

> - (Alice) I don't understand why they're here.
> - (Bob) I don't understand why they're here either. (Or just "I don't either" or "me neither.")

It is true that "too" and "as well" don't really work with negative clauses, nor does "also" in the second role (Alice/Bob example).

Comment: Thankyou so much. So I think same is the case with “as well”?

Comment: Yes it is; I edited the answer.

Comment: One more small doubt: Like in 1st condition with same subject,  (you) I don’t know who they are. (You) I don’t understand why they are here too. Is this wrong? Here too difffers from also?

Comment: That example isn't wrong, but may not mean what you expect. It means you don't know why they are here _in addition to other previously-stated people._ "Alice is here. I don't know why Bob is here too."

Comment: It is almost clear to me, please clarify this also . “I was targeted during Nixon's administration. Trump shouldn't make an enemies list, too.” This is a heading from a news paper. So what does this mean? 1)Trump shouldn't make a list(like shopping list) and an enemies list too. 2)Trump should not make an enemies list as Nixon did.
Nixon made an enemies list. An enemies list should not be made by Trump, too

Answer (score 1):

Too, As Well, and Also are usually used in positive sentences. The only difference is in their placement in the sentence. Too and as well are used at the end of a sentence. (As well is more formal than too). Also usually goes before the verb or adjective.

Example:

She likes movies.

1. I like movies too
2. I also like movies
3. I like movies as well.

To express an agreement in negative sentences, Either is used. Either usually comes at the end of a sentence.

Example:

She doesn't like soccers, I don't like soccers either.

However, it is possible to have a positive sentence and agree with a negative sentence and vice versa.

example:
1. Joni is doing bad at science class (positive sentence), he doesn't really like the teacher either. (negative sentence)
2. The new DC movie isn't that good (negative sentence), and I also prefer Marvel's. (Positive Sentence)